# PDO insert error php

Tags: php, insert, pdo

I'm trying to use the following script to inset values taken from a hidden form in to the database

```
 /detect user session
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
 {
//if no session take to login page
header('location:login_main.php');
 }

 //if session detected connect to database using pdo
 $db = getConnection();

 //get holiday infor from hidden form
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

 //insert the values in to favorties table
 $sql = "INSERT INTO saved_holidays (subscriberID, link, pubDate, title, description, dateSaved) 
VALUES (:subscriberID, :link, :pubDate, :title, :description, now())";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':subscriberID', $user);
$stmt->bindParam(':link', $link);
$stmt->bindParam(':pubDate',$date);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description);
$stmt->execute();

echo 'you have sucessfully saved the holiday offer.<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=index.php" />';
```

however when i run the script i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity     constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails     (`unn_w11023553/saved_holidays`, CONSTRAINT `holidays_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriberID`)     REFERENCES `subscriber` (`email`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in [OMISSIS]
```

can someone please tell what i've done wrong, thanks

Comment: Off topic: you have a huge security hole in your script. header("Location: ...") doesn't quit the execution of the script!

Answer (score 1):

This might be not a PHP problem: maybe you just violated a [foreign key constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). If you don't know about foreign key constraints, please, stop writing your application right now, and throughfully read the Wikipedia article I linked.

Some questions:

- Did you design the database yourself, or you are just using it? Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the table you're inserting stuff into?
- Did you check that the `$user` variable is correctly set, by `echo`-ing it?
- Did you try to execute the prepared statement by hardcoding the `$title`, `$link`, `$date`, and `$description` values?

Off topic: you have a huge security hole in your script. `header("Location: ...")` [**doesn't quit the execution of the script**](http://kristofmattei.be/2009/04/14/php-code-security-problem-with-header%E2%80%9Clocation-%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D/)!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `subscriberID` field in the `saved_holidays` table references the field `email` in your `subscriber` table.

Could you show us some data samples?

I guess you did not insert an existing subscriber's email in the `subscriberID` field.